# What is the easiest way to add a tooltip to a boxplot(ggplot) generated through Shiny?

Tags: ggplot2, shiny, ggplotly

I need the y-value displayed in a tooltip-style text box when the cursor hovers over a bar. I have to imagine this is a simple function through Shiny, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

I'll include the relevant UI and server code below:

UI :

```
#TAB 3 (QUOTA/SALES) 
  tabPanel(title = "Quota/Sales", 
           fluidRow(column(9,
                wellPanel(height=600, width ="100%",
                    plotOutput("quota", height=550,  width ="100%"
          ))),
              column(3,
                 wellPanel(height=100, width ="100%",
  selectInput("countyquota", "County:", choices=countychoices, selected = "Statewide"))))
          )))
```

Server:

```
      hdata <- reactive({
    if(input$sexage == "All" & input$countyharv == "Statewide") {
      harvdata}
      else if(input$sexage == "All" & input$countyharv != "Statewide")
    {filter(harvdata, NAME == input$countyharv)}
      else if (input$sexage != "All" & input$countyharv != "Statewide")
      {filter(harvdata, sexage == input$sexage, NAME == input$countyharv)}
      else if (input$countyharv == "Statewide" & input$sexage != "All"){
        filter(harvdata, sexage == input$sexage)
      }
      })
  output$harv <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(hdata(), aes(fill=sexage, y=harvest, x=year, label = harvest)) +
        geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
        xlab("Year") +
        ylab("Harvest") +
        labs(fill = NULL)+
        theme_bw()
    })`
```

Comment: ggplot2 output does not show tooltip, you should use another type of output, like plolty.

Answer (score 1):

`ggplot2` output by default does not show tooltip, you need to use a JavaScript base library for that. The more common are [`plotly`](https://plotly.com/r/line-and-scatter/) and [`highcharter`](https://jkunst.com/highcharter/).

Lets create a shiny app using the mtcars dataset to show you how to take `ggplot2` plots to `plotly` using the `plotly::ggplotly()` function.

> Note the important comments within the code.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly) # you need this packages

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput('x', 'X axis', choices = names(mtcars), selected = 'wt'),
  selectInput('y', 'Y axis', choices = names(mtcars), selected = 'mpg'),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 6,
      plotOutput('static'),
    ),
    column(
      width = 6,
      # New function to render plotly outputs
      plotlyOutput('dynamic')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # This a regular ggplot2 object. 
  plot <- reactive({
    ggplot(
        data = mtcars, 
        mapping = aes(x = .data[[input$x]], y = .data[[input$y]])
         ) +
      geom_point() +
      theme_bw()
  })
  
  output$static <- renderPlot({ plot() })
  # 1- New render frunction to handel plotly outputs
  # 2- Place a ggplot2 object within the ggplotly() function
  output$dynamic <- renderPlotly({ ggplotly(plot()) })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]